# How can a Virtual PC with Windows XP install the East Asian Language? (or does any browser come with Chinese fonts?)

Tags: fonts, microsoft-virtual-pc, chinese, language-pack

How can a Virtual PC with Windows XP on it install the East Asian Language? (or does any browser come with Chinese fonts?)

After setting up a Virtual PC with Windows XP, if Chinese font is needed, then the usual way is to go to the Control Panel, select "Regional and Language" and go to the second tab and check the box "Install Files for East Asian Languages".

After clicking OK, it asks for the file

```
cplexe.exe
```

on the XP SP3 CD 3...  and is said to be about 230MB...

In such case, how can the language pack or fonts be installed?

(**Update**: I found that it is true for Windows 7's Virtual PC with XP on it, as well as the XP SP3 with IE 8 that can be downloaded in the link below.)

(I downloaded the virtual hard drive file .vhd from http://www.Microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en so there is no "CD 3"... there)

Or does any browser come with all the unicode fonts without needing the OS to support it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the answer that people are looking for.
I was able to install East Asian languages **using my windows XP SP2 CD.**
One thing that I noticed in this installation process is that 
when I selected location of cplexe.exe on XP CD, installation failed.
I realized that CD drive also shows up as a hard drive in virtual XP, 
when I selected location of cplexe.exe on virtual hard drive (?) of CD drive, 
installation was successful.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the ISO file of Windows xp SP3 from the Microsoft Download Center site: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=2FCDE6CE-B5FB-4488-8C50-FE22559D164E&displaylang=en . It is free. You can then mount that ISO file on a virtual CD drive to complete the install.